# Can't do 2 joins on an MS Access query?

Tags: ms-access

So I have checked all the names etc are correct, the query works with only one of the joins not both with a syntax error:

```
SELECT *, Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1 
FROM Invoice_Accounts 
RIGHT JOIN  Delivery_Points ON Invoice_Accounts.Account_No = Delivery_Points.Account_No  
RIGHT JOIN Companies ON Invoice_Accounts.account_id = Companies.Company_No
```

This is the query I want to run but it comes up with the error:

```
syntax error (missing operator)
```

**UPDATE**:

using:

```
SELECT  *, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1 
FROM    (Invoice_Accounts 
        RIGHT JOIN  Delivery_Points 
            ON Invoice_Accounts.Account_No = Delivery_Points.Account_No)
        RIGHT JOIN Companies 
            ON Invoice_Accounts.account_id = Companies.Company_No
```

Gets me the error "JOIN expression not supported"

Comment: remove the `*,` do you get results?  Now add `Invoice_Accounts.*,` instead of `*,` do you still get results?   The problem is I think you can't use * with other field names.  You have to specify `tablename.*` when referencing additional fields in the select beyond just a *

Comment: nope, still same problem, it works with one of the joins both queries `SELECT *, Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1 
FROM Invoice_Accounts 
RIGHT JOIN  Delivery_Points ON Invoice_Accounts.Account_No = Delivery_Points.Account_No` and `SELECT *, Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1 
FROM Invoice_Accounts 
RIGHT JOIN Companies ON Invoice_Accounts.account_id = Companies.Company_No` work

Comment: Wait is this MS Access? or SQL server... you may just need ()'s around the joins if access.

Comment: yes it is, does that make a difference tried using ()'s

Comment: http://nm1m.blogspot.com/2007/10/multiple-left-joins-in-ms-access.html  yep ()'s matter as access can't figure out the order of the joins.

Comment: @xQbert I think you misunderstood, I tried using ()'s, I meant does it make a dif if it was MS Access or SQL Server, which of course also matters :)

Comment: @xQbert also tried that way; `SELECT * FROM ((Invoice_Accounts AS a) RIGHT JOIN Delivery_Points AS b ON a.Account_No = b.Account_No) RIGHT JOIN Companies AS c ON a.Company_Name = c.Company_No` and welcomed by the join not supported error again, solved now though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer eventually:

`SELECT Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1, *`

`FROM (Companies 
RIGHT JOIN Invoice_Accounts ON Companies.Company_No = Invoice_Accounts.Company_Name
)`

`RIGHT JOIN Delivery_Points ON Invoice_Accounts.Account_No = Delivery_Points.Account_No;`

The issue arises from ancient ms-access technologies where you can't right join to the same table more than once!

Comment: For future readers, I have to comment on your last statement. It has nothing to do with _ancient MS-Access technologies_ but SQL scripting. Your updated query in original post might work if you changed the second `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` or use a [self join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) with a second Invoice_Accounts table. Your updated query tried to right join to the same table (think two arrows pointing in) but outside tables can't relate to each other. This can be easier to see in the Query Design view.

Comment: Changing the second to a left join didn't work, isn't this mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

In Access you need to use parenthesis around joins if you have more than one:

```
SELECT  *, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Title AS t1, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Forename AS f1, 
        Invoice_Accounts.Surname AS s1 
FROM    (Invoice_Accounts 
        RIGHT JOIN  Delivery_Points 
            ON Invoice_Accounts.Account_No = Delivery_Points.Account_No)
        RIGHT JOIN Companies 
            ON Invoice_Accounts.account_id = Companies.Company_No
```

Two extend this, if you had three joins, you would need another set of parentheses:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (( A
        INNER JOIN  B 
            ON B.AID = A.AID)
        INNER JOIN C 
            ON C.BID = B.BID)
        INNER JOIN D
            ON D.CID = C.CID;
```

---

**EDIT**

I did not know that you could not `RIGHT JOIN` to the same table twice, so the above is an error, having said that I have never used a `RIGHT JOIN` in production code in my life, I would be inclined to switch to the more widely used `LEFT JOIN` and change the order of the tables:

```
SELECT  *, 
        ia.Title AS t1, 
        ia.Forename AS f1, 
        ia.Surname AS s1 
FROM    (Companies AS c
        LEFT JOIN Invoice_Accounts AS ia
            ON ia.account_id = c.Company_No)
        LEFT JOIN  Delivery_Points AS dp
            ON ia.Account_No = dp.Account_No;
```

*N.B. I have used aliases to reduce the amount of text in the query, this (in my opinion) makes them easier to read*

Comment: if they are inner joins the ()'s won't matter.  It applies if outer joins are occurring to the same table. If they are linear it works fine without ()'s A-->B-->C.  if it's A-->B  and A-->C as in this case then ()'s matter.

Comment: Sorry, random copy and paste error meant there was an extra word at the end.

Comment: @xQbert The same rules apply to inner joins, running `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN  B ON B.AID = A.AID INNER JOIN C ON C.BID = B.BID` will still throw a syntax error.

Comment: The result is still the same, apparently you cant right join on the same table twice :o