# Translating MySQL Queries to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a very old project which uses MySQL, which I am considering converting part of to MS Access. I'm running into problems with some of the more complex queries, and wondered if there is a reference which details the differences between Access's SQL and MySQL. For example, I have the following query:

```
select P.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.MiddleName, P.LastName,
       PR.LastName as MarriedName, P.Born, LocID, PlaceName,
       City, County, State, Country
from   persons P
         left join relatives R on (R.Person = P.PersonID and TookName)
         left join persons PR on (PR.PersonID = R.Relative)
         left join locations L on (L.Person = P.PersonID and L.FromDate = P.Born)
where  not P.Deleted
  and  (P.FirstName in ('Alan','Albert','Alfred','Allan','Allen','Alvin','Al')
   or   P.MiddleName in ('Alan','Albert','Alfred','Allan','Allen','Alvin','Al')
   or   P.Nickname in ('Alan','Albert','Alfred','Allan','Allen','Alvin','Al'))
  and  (P.LastName = 'Little' or PR.LastName = 'Little')
group  by P.PersonID
order  by P.Born desc
```

In Access, I can get as far as the first `join`:

```
select P.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.MiddleName, P.LastName,
       PR.LastName as MarriedName, P.Born
from   persons P
         left join relatives R on (R.Person = P.PersonID and TookName)
where  not P.Deleted
  and  P.FirstName in ('Alan','Albert','Alfred','Allan','Allen','Alvin','Al')
```

if I add the second join it says, `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(R.Person = P.PersonID and TookName) left join persons PR on (PR.PersonID = R.Relative.'`

Clicking the Help button very helpfully informs me, `The expression you typed is not valid for the reason indicated in the message.` Gee thanks!

But I have some other rather complex queries, so beyond solving the problem with this one, I'm looking for something that will explain the differences in general.

EDIT:

So, I changed the query according to the answer linked to:

```
select P.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.MiddleName, P.LastName,
       PR.LastName as MarriedName, P.Born
from   (persons P
         left join relatives R on R.Person = P.PersonID and TookName=true)
         left join persons PR on PR.PersonID = R.Relative
where  not P.Deleted
  and  P.FirstName in ('Alan','Albert','Alfred','Allan','Allen','Alvin','Al')
```

It tells me `JOIN expression not supported`, and highlights `TookName=true`. I also tried it as `TookName=1` and just `TookName`. I tried removing the second `JOIN`, with the first in parentheses, and it still just tells me `JOIN expression not supported`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't do 2 joins on an MS Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479690/cant-do-2-joins-on-an-ms-access-query)

Comment: Which table does `TookName` belong to? Specify the alias and put another pair of parentheses around the `ON` part: `(persons P left join relatives R on (R.Person = P.PersonID and x.TookName=true))` -- see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev&forum=accessdev

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might also consider keeping the MySQL backend and using Access as frontend with linked tables and/or PassThrough queries that keep using MySQL syntax.

Comment: @Andre `TookName` belongs to `relatives`. But the extra parentheses did it; that MSDN post covers it. Funny thing is, per MySQL syntax, I had them there, but took them off when I read that SO post you linked to :) Too bad there's not some consolidated reference for migrating queries; I'll probably run into more. WRT your note, I'm converting a PHP app to VB for an honors project in VB class (for which I'm required to seek outside help). I would like to stick with MySQL, and SQLite for local storage, but haven't figured those out yet, so just exploring Access to keep my options open.

Comment: As Andre suggested combine MySQL and Access, not a real miracle with ODBC [Using Microsoft Access as a Front-end to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) and [Using Connector/ODBC with Microsoft Applications](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft.html) I use this for years.

Comment: @BitAccesser An interesting option. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Access SQL parser is a huge fan of parentheses.

They are needed in all JOINs with more than 2 tables

```
FROM (a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id) JOIN c on b.id = c.id
```

so that only two tables / subqueries are joined in one set of parentheses.

And (as I learned today) they are needed around the `ON` clause if you want to use literal values in it.

```
FROM (a JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id AND b.foo = True)) JOIN c on b.id = c.id
```

An extended description is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev). Link was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632282/3820271

Answer (score 0):

the part  `left join relatives R on (R.Person = P.PersonID and TookName)`

seems not complete  (or not a valid sql expression)

`tookName` is not compared with nothings

could be you need somthings like :

```
left join relatives R on R.Person = P.PersonID and R.TookName = P.TookName
```

or

```
left join relatives R on R.Person = P.PersonID and R.TookName = 'FIXED VALUE'
```

or

```
left join relatives R on R.Person = P.PersonID and R.TookName is not null
```

for cross platform where on boolean you should use

```
  left join relatives R on R.Person = P.PersonID and R.TookName =1
```

or better  WHERE your_column <> 0

Comment: `TookName` is a boolean, indicating whether a married person took their spouse's family name. The whole query works fine in MySQL, and the partial query (including that field) works fine in Access, it just blows up when I add the second join.

Comment: answer  update  in some platform the implicit where on boolean is not allowed  so you can check for true =1 or false =  0

Comment: and tookname = true.

Comment: @xQbert   .. thanks  ..  .. for the useful suggestion