# Hmm, Translating MySQL to MS Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

*Below is the `MySQL` code I am looking to translate `mysql` to `ms-access`.
Exact help is of course super nice - but better understanding the logic is fine too if it helps me work this out (which would help me in other such queries I want to run)*

**thank you in advance** :)

```
'''// Law report for  // 
select
    b.bib_id as 'Bib ID',
    b.status as 'Bib Status',
//    b.created_by as 'Created by',
//    b.date_created as 'Date created',
//    b.updated_by as 'Updated by',
//    b.date_updated as 'Date updated',
    h.holdings_id as 'Holdings ID',
   h.location as 'Location',
    h.call_number as 'Call Number',
    i.updated_by as 'Updated by',
    i.date_updated as 'Date updated',
    n.note as 'Item note'
from ole_ds_bib_t b
join ole_ds_holdings_t h on b.bib_id = h.bib_id
join ole_ds_item_t i on h.holdings_id = i.holdings_id
join ole_ds_item_note_t n on i.item_id = n.item_id
where 
    h.location like '%Law%' and 
    n.type = 'nonPublic' and 
    n.note regexp '^[[:alpha:]]{6}$' and 
    n.note not in ('folder', 'binder', 'SLAVEX', 'NISORI') and
   i.date_updated between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-31';'''
```

Comment: MySQL to Access? Quite a backwards step! The only thing that won't really work out there is the regex bit.. You might be able to fudge it with `Not ALike "%[0-9]%"` and a length check

Comment: [MS Access doesn't have a regex operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539359/16587); this question needs the data structure of the postgres table; the data structure of the ms access table; the types at play; and relationships.

Comment: I agree, not ideal. This example should help me (I think): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506748/translating-mysql-queries-to-ms-access

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sql as written should work just fine,  EXCEPT for this:

```
n.note regexp '^[[:alpha:]]{6}$'
```

Access does not support or have reg expressions.

It not clear what the "^" is in above, but if you looking for 6 characters?

then

```
n.note like "??????"
```

So your problem is not the sql - it looks ok. The issue is changing the regexpresison to a like command in Access sql. You have to explain what the regexp does, and then we can see if the like command in Access can recreate this ability.